# LAN connection is unstable

Tags: windows-10, networking, internet-connection

I recently bought a new PC with Windows 10.

I have it connected to an ethernet LAN internet that I have used with my previous PC and had no problem using it.

However, when after I shut down or put it to sleep mode and then turn it back on, the internet becomes really slow or sometimes doesn't even work (saying it is unidentified network)

The weird thing is that when I restart the PC (i.e. press the restart button instead of shutdown-power on), everything is fine again and my internet is as fast as ever.

My drivers are all reinstalled and updated as well.

As this is still quite an inconvenience, I was wondering if anyone knows what is happening and how I can fix this.

Comment: Contact the manufacturer support line and ask for warranty support. LAN cards that are working correctly do not do this.

Comment: I would try turning off the power management on this adapter. To disable this setting in Device Manager, expand Network Adapters, right-click the adapter, select Properties, select the Power Management tab, and then clear the Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power check box. If this does nothing, try disabling "Fast Startup" for Windows 10 (Google can help). Failing that, I would contact support from the  manufacturer.

Comment: @acejavelin apparently my network adapter doesn't have a power management tab. But disabling Fast Startup seems to have solved the problem! Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Network troubleshooter?  It has straightened out many problems for me.
(Right click network icon in system tray - Troubleshoot problems)

Comment: I tried that before but usually just told me to reset my router, which I did but still didn't fix anything

Answer (score 0):

This can occasionally be caused by Windows [Fast Startup feature](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/) which an excellent description of is included in the linked article, but here is the jist of it. At shutdown when fast startup is enabled, Windows doesn't really shutdown... Instead it logs of user and closes programs and gets to a mostly clean boot state, then hibernates, writing an image of the RAM and system state to a file. "Powering on" from this point can be noticeably faster then Windows doing a full startup sequence, loading the kernel, drivers, and system state from a file rather than re-initializing everything like normal.

This can also have some drawbacks and issues with some systems, disk encryption, drivers, multi-OS systems, BIOS/UEFI firmware access, and systems that in general just don't deal with hibernation well.

Since we have looked at most of the common issues with drivers, settings, cables, etc. It is worth it to try to disable this feature since the issue mainly appears at "startup" and on a restart/reboot the condition does not occur. This is a significant clue that the issue could be related to this, because a restart/reboot is NOT effected by the Fast Startup feature and a full shutdown, power cycle, and clean boot occurs on a reboot.

To check the setting and disable it, open the `Start Menu` and type ***power options*** and select it from menu. Then select `Choose what the power buttons do` from the control panel menu on right. On that page, scroll down to `Shutdown Settings`.

Here you will see `Turn on fast startup (recommended)` and if this is the first time you have been to this menu option, it will likely be grayed out and you cannot change it. If it is not grayed out, untick the option and click `Save Changes` and then reboot. If it is grayed out, scroll back up to the top of the page and you will find an option that says `Change settings that are currently unavailable` to enable the setting to be changed, untick the option, click `Save changes` and reboot.

Note that this setting can get turned back on by Windows Updates on occasion, so if the problem recurs later you may need to repeat this process.